# How to go to implementation with mouse click?

Tags: visual-studio-code

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> goes to the **definition**.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> goes to the **definition** in another tab.

But how can I go to **implementation** with the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, at the time of this writing, you can't. But if the feature request [Allow customization of mouse shortcuts #3130](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3130) goes through, you could. I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

Answer (score -1):

Probably not what you're expecting, but the easiest way with mouse is `right click` and then select `Go to implementations`.